# Stuck on Checking battery state at startup in Ubuntu, have splash screen no startup

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  When I boot up the computer it goes to the splash but there is no login screen, just the purple background and the mouse cursor.  "Checking battery state" is the last line that does not have an "[OK]". When I press Ctr-alt-shift-F1 I can login and sudo stop gdm and startx.  However this makes it so that the applets don't show.
Error: "The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID:GNOME_notificationAreaApplet" and does it for every single applet.  Everything else works fine though.

I get a EHCI: BIOS handoff failed twice in the dmesg as well.

The laptop has intel mobile integrated graphics.

UPDATE:  Now my desktop has the exact same problem.

Things that I have tried:
Changing to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.modeset=1 acpi=off"

Comment: Have you tried unchecking Power Manager (or Power Management or whatever it is) from the startup items?

Comment: Yes I have.  I've also tried most of the fixes here :https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes.  Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone that have this issue: How much free space do you have on your Hard drive? Too little space can cause Gnome power management to stop. Try to free some space using a live cd (let´s say 5 gb) and reboot your machine. Now it should start normally.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is out of date, but for the next person with a *buntu that hangs at "Checking Battery State ... [OK]": <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login to terminal, then:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-power-manger
```

followed by a restart, worked for me.

Just reinstalls the default configuration for gnome-power-manager, which was apparently causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GRUB2 bootloader, you can edit the boot parameters to turn ACPI (and thus the message) off.

After it hangs on "Check Battery State," press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter a terminal. Log in, then open up `nano` to edit the GRUB2 configuration file: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Search for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and correct it to be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off"`.

Save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and update the bootloader with the new settings: `sudo update-grub`

Then reboot:`sudo reboot`